in GA4，the daily exported events are about to exceed 1 million. What should I do next?
I am using the Daily Export method to export some GA events to BigQuery, but the daily event volume is about to exceed 1 million. If I switch to the Streaming method, I might lose information such as Traffic Source/channel_group. I want to scale up the data volume while retaining these attribution details. How can I achieve this?
I would like to obtain raw GA logs for days with over 1 million events, including complete and accurate traffic sources and channel labels,and ultimately import these logs into Redshift
Any alternative method that achieves the same result would be acceptable

Standard GA4 properties have a BigQuery Export limit of 1 million events for Daily (batch) exports.
If a standard property significantly exceeds the one-million-event daily limit, Analytics may pause daily exports immediately (and previous days’ exports will not be reprocessed).
So, or you pay for GA4 360 properties or you can exclude specific data streams and events from your export, either to limit the size of your export or to make sure you're exporting just the events you want in BigQuery:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9823238?hl=en#datafiltering&zippy=%2Cin-this-article
